# Cassandra - recovery of data after accidental delete

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, recovery, data-recovery

As the data in case of Cassandra is physically removed during compaction, is it possible to access the recently deleted data in any way? I'm looking for something similar to Oracle Flashback feature (`AS OF TIMESTAMP`).

Also, I can see the pieces of deleted data in the relevant commit log file, however it's obviously unreadable. Is it possible to convert this file to a more readable format?

Comment: theoretically (not sure still), you can do `nodetool flush`, then stop writing the data, then use `sstabledump` to dump data into JSON format and recover from it, ignoring the tombstones.

Comment: Unfortunately the data was still in the memtable when it was deleted (the tombstone overwrote the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to execute a restore from your commitlog.
The safest is to copy the commitlog to a new cluster (with same schema), and restore following the instructions (comments) from `commitlog_archiving.properties` file. In your case, you will want to set `restore_point_in_time` to a time between your insert and your delete.

Comment: Just a few points to add to this answer from a practical perspective: it was actually enough to leverage the commitlog replay behavior during Cassandra startup. I shut down the development node, removed the commitlog files and uploaded the one containing deleted data. It was necessary, however, to change the IDs of the target tables in system_schema.tables (or recreate them including the ID in the CREATE TABLE statement) to match the original ones. Otherwise the mutations would be skipped (CommitLogReplayer.java:147 - Skipped 9 mutations from unknown (probably removed) CF with id ...).